# How do the jQuery onload code reusable for thumbnails 2 and 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

The application I'm building has three input[type="file"]'s. The first upload input targets thumbnail 1, the second upload input targets the second thumbnail, etc. The jQuery onload code works for the first thumbnail. Is there anyway to make the code reusable for thumbnails 2 and 3 without repeating the code?

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var files = $("input[type=file]");
  files.change(function(e) {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $(".thumbnail-one img").attr("src", e.target.result);
        $('.full-image img').attr("src", e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $('.full-image').html($(this).html());
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  background-color: lavender;
  border: 10px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 720px;
}

legend {
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}

fieldset div {
  margin: 10px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.full-image {
  width: 580px;
  height: 580px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  float: right;
}

.full-image img {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<title>Image Gallery App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Your Images</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required="">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box thumbnail-one">
      <img src="https://http.cat/100" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="box thumbnail-two">
      <img src="https://http.cat/405" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="box thumbnail-three">
      <img src="https://http.cat/504" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="full-image">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <img src="https://http.cat/100" id="expandedImg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add new `attribute` `data-thumb` to you input and add respective thumbnail class here like `data-thumb='thumbnail-one'` `data-thumb='thumbnail-two'`.
   Your input will look like `<input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" data-thumb='one' required="">`
2. Use `let thumb = $(this).data('thumb');` to Get thumbnail class value inside `files.change(function(e) {...}`. **Note** you can also use `let thumb = $(this).attr('data-thumb');`.
3. Use `$("." + thumb + " img").attr("src", e.target.result);` as selector.

**P.S** As mentioned by @AlwaysHelping in comment and also as per the recommended you should always use unique `id` values. Because if you use `#avatar` it will always return `first` element in the `DOM` with `id = avatar`. Also in form `postback` it can cause issue.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var files = $("input[type=file]");
  files.change(function(e) {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      let thumb = $(this).data('thumb');
      // let thumb = $(this).attr('data-thumb'); // alternative to above line.
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("." + thumb + " img").attr("src", e.target.result);
        $('.full-image img').attr("src", e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $('.full-image').html($(this).html());
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  background-color: lavender;
  border: 10px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 720px;
}

legend {
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}

fieldset div {
  margin: 10px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.full-image {
  width: 580px;
  height: 580px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  float: right;
}

.full-image img {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<title>Image Gallery App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Your Images</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar1" name="avatar1" data-thumb='thumbnail-one' required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar2" name="avatar2" data-thumb='thumbnail-two' required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar3" name="avatar3" data-thumb='thumbnail-three' required="">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box thumbnail-one">
      <img src="https://http.cat/100" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="box thumbnail-two">
      <img src="https://http.cat/405" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="box thumbnail-three">
      <img src="https://http.cat/504" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="full-image">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <img src="https://http.cat/100" id="expandedImg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function imgUploaded(event, thumbnail){
    var fileInput = event.target;
    if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("." +thumbnail +" img").attr("src", e.target.result);
        $('.full-image img').attr("src", e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $('.full-image').html($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  background-color: lavender;
  border: 10px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 720px;
}

legend {
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}

fieldset div {
  margin: 10px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.full-image {
  width: 580px;
  height: 580px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  float: right;
}

.full-image img {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<title>Image Gallery App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Your Images</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" onchange="imgUploaded(event, 'thumbnail-one')" name="avatar" required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" onchange="imgUploaded(event, 'thumbnail-two')" name="avatar" required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
    <input type="file" onchange="imgUploaded(event, 'thumbnail-three')" name="avatar" required="">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box thumbnail-one">
      <img src="https://http.cat/100" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="box thumbnail-two">
      <img src="https://http.cat/405" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="box thumbnail-three">
      <img src="https://http.cat/504" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="full-image">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <img src="https://http.cat/100" id="expandedImg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```